# Unable to copy file "xxx" to "bin/debug/xxx.deploy". Could not find a part of the path

Tags: vb.net

I developed a vb.net project and built it successfully. but while publishing, I got an error Unable to copy file "Resources\xxxxxxx.xlsx" to "bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1_0_0_90\Resources\xxxxxxxx.xlsx.deploy". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_1_0_0_90\Resources\xxxxxxxx.xlsx.deploy'.

I couldnt find the reason for the issue. Tried reopening the project rebuilding and republishing several times.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. The problem was the file name. The filename was too long. I saved the project inside Document folder within many sub folder. Thats why the filename became too long. I copied the project and placed insinde Documents folder directly and tried publishing. It was successfull.

Thank you